# How to Create Color Indicator in Column sharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, color-field

I have sharepoint list with clasic view mode.
in that list I have: Task Name, PC Name, Planned Start Date, Planned Due Date, Actual Start Date, Actual Completion Date, Alert Zone.

Alert Zone consists of:
-Zone 1 (Red Color)
-Zone 2 (Orange Color)
-Zone 3 (Green Color)

I create 2 custom view:
-Alert Zone View -> contains according to the existing items alert zone (by giving a color to a line item)
[image]

-All Items View -> contains according to the existing items without Alert Zone
[image]

All the custom views I made are different based on the script code that I updated in the content web part

Can I if I give color only to my Alert Zone column in All Items View with the existing Grouping View? My Grouping View Based On: Fixture Name and Voyage Seq

Comment: What are you using to color the list items/rows? JSLink or something else?

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap I use JS in Media Content Web Part, which I uploaded the file on Site Asset